Automatically citing a first bibliography in a second bibliography
Short version
I have a document where the bibligraphic information (from a .bib file) is printed twice, first in chronological order (with labels 1, 2, etc.), and then a second time in alphabetical order (with labels [A1], [A2], etc.). Note that [A1], the first entry in alphabetical order, is not the same entry as 1, the first entry in chronological order)—[A1] corresponds to [23] say.
How can I set up the second bibliography so that each entry automatically cites the corresponding entry in the first bibliography? So for instance, [23] appears in the entry for [A1] in the second bibliography.
Longer version
This question concerns a long annotated bibliography (100+ pages, 350+ entries in its soon-to-be-updated form) that requires an unusually delicate BibLaTeX setup. This manuscript has been the subject of several prior questions on this site, most importantly this first question and this second question (and, less relevant to the current matter, these third and fourth questions). Thanks to your help, we now have two well-formatted bibliographies in the manuscript: a first chronological bibliography that includes annotations of each source's contents, and a second alphabetical bibliography without annotations.
Right now, if a reader locates a source in the alphabetical bibliography (say [A1]), they can use the publication year to find the vicinity of where that source appears in the chronological bibliography; but they still have to scan through several entries before finding the one they want (say [23]) and reading its annotation. I would love to find a way where the alphabetical entries automatically include a citation to the corresponding entry in the chronological bibliography. So for instance, [A1] would include a [23] somewhere in addition to the author/title/etc. (I imagine if we can get it to appear anywhere, it's relatively easy to customize exactly where and how it appears.)
The two bibliographies are generated from the same .bib file, so each alphabetical entry “knows” its {ownlabel} and presumably would only need to insert \cite{ownlabel} somewhere along the way. But I certainly don't know how to make this happen … does anyone here?
Here's a minimal working example—a .tex file, a .bib file, and a biblatex.cfg file that could probably be made more minimal but I'm scared to mess with it too much—followed by its current output.
MWE.tex:
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitH, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,geometry,bm}
\geometry{left=1in, right=1in, top=.75in, bottom=.75in}
%BibLaTeX:
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mrnumber.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{mrnumber}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{mrnumber}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[sorting=ynt, backend=biber, datamodel=mrnumber, style=numeric-comp, isbn=false, sortcites, maxbibnames=99, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=ynt]{*}

\addbibresource{MWE.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\section*{Chronological bibliography}
\normalsize
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\section*{Alphabetic bibliography}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{-.2\baselineskip}
\togglefalse{showannotation}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A] 
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}

MWE.bib:
@article{2001,
author={Buthor, B.},
title={First work on the subject},
journal={Amazing J.},
volume={1},
year={2001},
pages={45--67},
annotation={The author established the fundamental facts about what are now called Buthorian thingoids.}
}
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@book{2002,
author={Duthor, D.},
title={A book, already},
publisher={Gutenberg Press},
year={2002},
annotation={The author synthesizes all known research on Buthorian thingoids. This book cites~\cites{2001}.}
}
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@incollection {2003,
author={Author, A.},
title={A conference paper},
booktitle={Buthorian thingoids (University of Alexandria)},
pages={141--168},
note={Conference Papers in Math., Vol. 123},
publisher={Gutenberg Press},
year={2003},
annotation={The author rediscovers some of the results of Buthor~\cite{2001} in weaker form.}
}
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@article {2004,
author={Cuthor, C.},
title={Equivariant {B}uthorian thingoids},
journal={J. Interesting Stuff},
fjournal={Journal of Interesting Stuff},
volume={999},
year={2004},
pages={241--253},
annotation={The author establishes more properties of Buthorian thingoids under an equivariance assumption. This article cites~\cites{2001,2003}.}
}
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@online{2005,
author={Cuthor, C.},
title={{B}uthorian ringoids}, 
year={2005},
url={https://arxiv.org/abs/1234.5678},
annotation={The author investigates analogues of Buthor's work in ring-like spaces. This article cites~\cites{2002,2003,2004}.}
}

biblatex.cfg:
%% Bibliography format:
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}


\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{doi}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{article}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{doi}%
}{}
}


%%%%% creating a style on biblatex similar to amsrefs:

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{mrnumber}{%
  MR%\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+eprint+url}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
    {\printfield{doi}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{mrnumber}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:url}
    {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
    {}}

%% Remove punctuation at the end of each bib entry
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}


\newtoggle{showannotation}
\toggletrue{showannotation}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iftoggle{showannotation}
    {\setunit{\addperiod\par}%
     \printfield{annotation}}
    {}%
  \finentry}

\setlength{\bibparsep}{.4\baselineskip}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.1\baselineskip}

\newlength{\bibparindent}
\setlength{\bibparindent}{0pt}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\bibparindent}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}



X-Y Problem thought: Would a dynamic table be a better modality for your information? Like this one I built. I see the current arXiv PDF has a lot of math, which may make a web-based table less feasible, but maybe it would help to know if your motivation for both bibliographies is to help readers easily find a particular paper?

@jessexknight Thanks for the suggestion, and I certainly see some advantages to a more database-style resource. This project is in its final stages, with the authors (including me) ready to move on, so for practical reasons we'll need to stick to the current format and make it as good as we can.

One thing I found is that you can use \thefield{entrykey} to get the entry name. So by using \cite{\thefield{entrykey}} in finentry hook, at least we can attempt to cite that entry.
But the problem is the sorting of the entries have been changed because of the \newrefcontext command before \printbibliography, which means they are sorted using different methods and have a prefix.
I am just pointing out this observation here as you may have a way to solve the sorting/formatting issue. I will look into it further when I have time.
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iftoggle{showannotation}
    {\setunit{\addperiod\par}%
     \printfield{annotation}\finentry}
    {\finentry~\cite{\thefield{entrykey}}}%
  }

UPDATE (08/06)
The following approach seems to work. In main LaTeX file, use \localrefcontext instead of \newrefcontext:
{
\localrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[heading=none]
}

Then in biblatex.cfg, use the following:
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iftoggle{showannotation}
    {\setunit{\addperiod\par}%
     \printfield{annotation}\finentry}
    {\finentry~{\localrefcontext[sorting=ynt]\cite{\thefield{entrykey}}}}%
  }


This is already a huge step forward, thank you! I found that if I deleted the .aux file, then this modification worked exactly as desired the first time I ran LaTeX; but then on the second LaTeX pass, the entries in the alphabetical bibliography cited their own A-numbers. I might not be able to control whether arXiv or a potential publisher does only a single LaTeX pass.... Is there a way to suppress certain entries in the .aux file, or some other great idea?

I feel like the \assignrefcontext... commands on p108 of the BibLaTeX documentation are designed for doing this sort of thing; but I couldn't immediately understand how they work and would still very much appreciate some help!

@GregMartin The updated approach seems to be working. Please verify.

Absolutely amazing! I'll double-check it tonight on the master file, but with the MWE and a larger WE it seems to work perfectly. Thank you so much—we'll definitely add your name to the acknowledgments!
